# How to insert data in Azure SQL using tedious.js after verifying that the data doesn't exists in the database?

Tags: node.js, express, tedious

This is the first time I'm using `tedious.js`, I still don't understand it a lot. I'm mostly going over their documentation [here](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/).

Following is the logic in the POST method.

- Check if the tag already exists for the given statement id
- If the tag exists, return the message to the client
- If the tag doesn't exist, insert the tag in the database.

This is my post method in `express.js` to add "tag"

```
 // POST add tags
 router.post('/tag', function(req, res){

     // get the body
     const data = req.body;    

     // sql query to check if the tag already exists for the given id or not. 
     let sql = `SELECT * FROM tags WHERE corporate_statement_link_id = @corporate_statement_link_id and name = @name FOR JSON PATH`;
     
      // sql query to insert the tag in the database
      let query = `INSERT INTO tags (corporate_statement_link_id, name) VALUES(@corporate_statement_link_id, @name)`;

     console.log("Getting tags");

     try {
         console.log("Checking if the tag '", data.name, "' exists for ", data.corporate_statement_link_id,".");

//This is where I'm using the tedious to make connection to Azure database
         var conn = sqldb.createConnection();

         var request = sqldb.createRequest(sql, conn);
         request.addParameter('corporate_statement_link_id', TYPES.Int, data.corporate_statement_link_id);
         request.addParameter('name', TYPES.VarChar, data.name);

         //=========>>>
         // This is where I'm not so sure what's happening and if I can call it this way. 
         // The reason I'm trying this is because var "request" is always undefined since it's done async?. so, even though the tag exists in the database, the code below to add the tag still runs. 
         var result = sqldb.runQuery(request, conn, res, '{}').then(d => {
             console.log(d);
         });
        //  console.log("Result: ", result);
         


         if(!request){
             console.log('the tag already exists')
            res.status(300).send("Tag already exist.");
         } else {
            console.log("Tag ",data.name, "doesn't exist.")
            console.log("Creating tag");

            // This is to add the tag to the database

            conn = sqldb.createConnection();
            request = sqldb.createRequest(query, conn);
            request.addParameter('corporate_statement_link_id', TYPES.Int, data.corporate_statement_link_id);
            request.addParameter('name', TYPES.VarChar, data.name);

            result = sqldb.runQuery(request, conn, res, '{}');
            console.log("Result: ", result);
            
            return result;  
         }


     } catch(err){
        res.send(err);
     }
```

**Azure Database Connection**

```
'use strict'

// function to create connection to the SQL database
function createConnection(){

    var AzureConfig = {
        authentication: {
          options: {
            userName: "username", 
            password: "password" 
          },
          type: "default"
        },
        server: "server", 
        options: {
          database: "database", 
          encrypt: true, 
          validateBulkLoadParameters: true
        }
    };

    // create connection to the database 
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var connection = new Connection(AzureConfig);
 
    return connection;
    
}// end create connection


// create query request
function createRequest(query, connection){

    var Request = require('tedious').Request;

    console.log("Creating new request");

    var req = new Request(query, function(err, rowCount) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            output.write(err);
        }

        connection && connection.close();
    });

    console.log("Request created..");

    return req;
}


// Running the query
function runQuery(query, connection, output, defaultContent){
    var request = query;
    
    if(typeof query == 'string'){
        request = createRequest(query, connection);
    }

    console.log("It's not a query but a request..");
    var empty = true;

    request.on('row', function(columns){
        console.log("Checking and running the row..");
        if(empty){
            console.log("Response fetched from SQL Database.");
            empty = false;
        
        }
        console.log("Columns found: ", columns[0].value);
        // console.log(output);
        output.write(columns[0].value);
        // console.log("returning data");
        // data.push(columns[0].value);
    });

    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more, rows){
        console.log("The request is done..");
        console.log(rowCount, "rows returned");
        // output.end();
        _OnDone(empty, defaultContent, output);
    });

    request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount, more, rows){
        console.log("The request procedure is done..");
        _OnDone(empty, defaultContent, output);
        console.log(rowCount, "rows returned");
        // output.end();
    });

    console.log("Executing request");
    executeRequest(request, connection);

}

function _OnDone(empty, defaultContent, output){
    if(empty){
        output.write(defaultContent);
        console.log('No results from database - default content is returned.');

    }

    try{
        
        console.log('Closing Http Response output.');
        // console.log("Output: ", output);
        output.end();
        
        
    } catch(err){
        // output.write(err);
        console.error(err);
    }
}

// execute request to pull the data
function executeRequest(request, connection){

    console.log("checking the connection..");
    
    connection.on('connect', function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            //output.write(err);
        }
        console.log("request executing...");
        console.log("Request: ", request);
        connection.execSql(request);
    });
}

module.exports.createConnection = createConnection;
module.exports.createRequest = createRequest;
module.exports.executeRequest = executeRequest;
module.exports.runQuery = runQuery;
```

**Error message and output**

```
Checking and running the row..
Response fetched from SQL Database.
Columns found:  [{"corporate_statement_link_id":3,"name":"black-lives-matter","id":11},{"corporate_statement_link_id":3,"name":"edi","id":12},{"corporate_statement_link_id":3,"name":"test","id":13},{"corporate_statement_link_id":3,"name":"test2","id":14},{"corporate_statement_link_id":3,"name":"test3","id":23},{"corporate_statement_link_id":3,"name":"test","id":24}]
The request procedure is done..
Closing Http Response output.
undefined rows returned
GET /api/v1/statements/tags/3 200 353.227 ms - -
Getting tags
Checking if the tag ' test4 ' exists for  3 .
Creating new request
Request created..
It's not a query but a request..
Executing request
checking the connection..
POST /api/v1/statements/tag 200 27.657 ms - 2
request executing...
Request:  Request {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    row: [Function],
    done: [Function],
    doneProc: [Function]
  },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  sqlTextOrProcedure: 'SELECT * FROM tags WHERE corporate_statement_link_id = @corporate_statement_link_id and name = @name FOR JSON PATH',
  parameters: [
    {
      type: [Object],
      name: 'corporate_statement_link_id',
      value: 3,
      output: false,
      length: undefined,
      precision: undefined,
      scale: undefined
    },
    {
      type: [Object],
      name: 'name',
      value: 'test4',
      output: false,
      length: undefined,
      precision: undefined,
      scale: undefined
    }
  ],
  parametersByName: {
    corporate_statement_link_id: {
      type: [Object],
      name: 'corporate_statement_link_id',
      value: 3,
      output: false,
      length: undefined,
      precision: undefined,
      scale: undefined
    },
    name: {
      type: [Object],
      name: 'name',
      value: 'test4',
      output: false,
      length: undefined,
      precision: undefined,
      scale: undefined
    }
  },
  originalParameters: [],
  preparing: false,
  canceled: false,
  paused: false,
  userCallback: [Function],
  handle: undefined,
  error: undefined,
  connection: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  rows: undefined,
  rst: undefined,
  rowCount: undefined,
  callback: [Function],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
The request procedure is done..
No results from database - default content is returned.
Closing Http Response output.
undefined rows returned
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:629:17)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:621:15)
    at _OnDone (C:\Users\shresthas\source\repos\statement-rater-app\routes\azure-db.js:99:16)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shresthas\source\repos\statement-rater-app\routes\azure-db.js:87:9)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\shresthas\source\repos\statement-rater-app\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:154:18)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shresthas\source\repos\statement-rater-app\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1323:19)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shresthas\source\repos\statement-rater-app\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:35:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:315:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:684:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

How can I resolve such that when the tag is found, it returns to the client bypassing the insert statement, but if the tag doesn't exist, I want to insert it and then send the tag to the client?

Comment: You really want to reduce this to a true [mcve]. Not even to improve your post, but because forcing yourself to go through _that process_ makes you discover the problem 99% of the time. The fact that you have an mcve at the end of it is just a bonus in case you didn't find the problem on your own.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Appreciate it. I'll get right on it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I read the information on mcve, but I'm struggling to make this a minimal reproducible code. I kind of know where the error is occuring, but I don't know how to resolve it. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: one of the things to realise is that you can hardcode _almost everything_. Any value you're pushing into your function calls can be hardcoded if you just want to reproduce a single problem case, which makes a lot of code 100% irrelevant: bootstrap a single-row databse, and show the single function call with all the values that would normally be user or even server-supplied: done. And, if that works, that's the whole point of the MCVE exercise: clearly it works so somewhere between pure code, and your code, things break. That's when you start introducing more code, one call at a time.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I'm still not able to get it to MCVE. I guess I have very limited understanding of `tedious.js` that I can't really understand how it's pulling the data from the sql server and sending it. The struggle that I'm encountering is with returning the results to a function that called the `runQuery` function. I see that it pulled the data and is printed out in the console, but still can't pass the data from `request.on('row'..` to the function that called `runquery`. That's why I'm having trouble doing mcve. Any pointers that I can try?

Comment: If you have a limited understanding of Tedious, I would strongly recommend going back to https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious/tree/master/examples and, with the docs on the side, starting with one of those and building it back up to what you're doing. If your own code is confusing you, take a few steps back to simpler, known to work, code and then reintroduce the things you need one by one, testing at each step that what you added, does what it's supposed to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that's exactly what I'm doing right now. But the things that are lacking in the documentation is how the response from Azure SQL with `FOR JSON PATH` is handled. I see in the console that the request is sent as a json array but in multiple batches; request.on('row', row) runs 3 times for me. Also, the documentation and example doesn't show how the data is being sent to the client, it only prints to the console. I'm trying by pushing the json array to an array and trying to return it to the function to be sent to the client, but the value never gets returned. Lot to learn

Comment: `request.on...` happens _in response_to your `execSQL` call. So seeing the row callback happen three times is pretty normal: `request.on('row', ...)` will trigger once for each row in the query result, so if the query yields a table with three rows, it'll get called three times (after which `request.on('done', ...)` gets called to tell you there's no more data). And if you have a table with two million rows, it will get called two million times before `done` is triggered (yikes! remember to LIMIT calls!). That said: buffering the rows until `done` is fine, but your code for that is weird.

Comment: Allocate a fresh `const output = []` in your `runQuery` (don't pass it in as argument), and push results into that as part of `on('row',...)`. Then on done, call your `onDone` function with that output as one of the arguments (you already do that, so good). However, the question is then "what do you want to DO with that data" because right now your POST response code has `result = sqldb.runQuery(request, conn, res, '{}'); ...; return result;` which makes no sense: there is nothing to return, `runQuery` is asynchronous, and anything that needs to happen once it done needs to be a callback.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks. Yeah, that code was based on my limited understanding. After your suggestion about mcve, I've changed my code drastically. I'm getting the hang of it now. (You must be a really good teacher.). Seemingly, my query has "FOR JSON PATH", so it emits 'row' as stored procedure three times; I have 1000 rows of data. I can see it in the terminal how it prints. I'm trying to figure out how to save the results in an array. After `request.on('row', row);request.on('doneProc', requestDone);console.log("Values: ", values);`, I can see it calling `requestDone`

Comment: I have updated the `result=sqldb..` also. It now has `res.send(sqldb...)` where it's expecting the values from `runQuery`. So, I need to go and figure out how to do `callback`.

Comment: callbacks are pretty much the basis of how most older Node APIs work: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/ (modern code will use Promises with .then/.catch, or will use `async` and `await` operators, which are technically just Promises but with a nicer syntax). When it comes to callbacks, you either create or reference a function that is to be called ("called back") all the way at the end, and then you keep passing that down your function calls. E.g. `function runQuery(..., onDone)` and calling `runQuery(..., (result) => { res.json(result); });`

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, Thank you so much for your patience and bearing with me to help me through this. I think I got it now. I just checked on the chrome network panel, I see the data. I have some thing to do now. Thank you so much again. callback was a great help.

Comment: Good to hear: I'd encourage you to write out your solution as an answer (explaining you were doing wrong in addition to the updated code of course), so you can accept that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the massive help from @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I was able to revisit my codes and fix the issue I was having. Thank you so much @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Your way of showing me the path was massively helpful in helping me understand the problem - better than simply giving the answer.

Also, another thanks goes to @mauridb who helped me a lot with a cool and better way to write the `SQL` query.

Here's what my `azure-sql.js` looks like now:

```
'use strict'

// function to create connection to the SQL database
function createConnection(){

    var AzureConfig = {
        authentication: {
          options: {
            userName: "username", 
            password: "password" 
          },
          type: "default"
        },
        server: "server", 
        options: {
          database: "database", 
          encrypt: true, 
          validateBulkLoadParameters: true
        }
    };

    // create connection to the database 
    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
    var connection = new Connection(AzureConfig);
 
    return connection;
    
}// end create connection
// function to configure request to be sent to the SQL server
function configureRequest(sql, conn, parameters){

    var request = createRequest(sql, conn);
    
    parameters.forEach(function(param){
        request.addParameter(param.name, param.type, param.data);
    });

    return request;

}


// create query request
function createRequest(query, connection){

    var Request = require('tedious').Request;

    var req = new Request(query, function(err, rowCount) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);

        }

        connection && connection.close();
    });

    return req;
}


// Running the query
function runQuery(query, connection, callback){
    var request = query;
    
    if(typeof query == 'string'){
        request = createRequest(query, connection);
    }

    var values = '';

    // the rows are returned as a json array. Since it's sent in a batch, 
    // different events are raised. 
    // So the values are concatenated to create a single JSON object
    request.on('row', function(column) {
        values += column[0].value;
    });

    
    // if anything specific needs to be done after the process is complete
    request.on('done', function(rowCount, more, rows){
       
        // check if the SQL Server returned anything
        values = checkValues(values);
        
        callback(values);

    });

    // if anything specific needs to be done after the stored procedure is complete
    // however, if we use connection.execSql(), it emits doneProc instead of done.
    request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount, more, rows){

        // check if the SQL Server returned anything
        values = checkValues(values);    
        callback(values);

    });

    try {
        executeRequest(request, connection);
    } catch(err){
        throw err
    }

    // return the values parsed as JSON
    // return JSON.parse(values);
    return values;
}


// function to check values if the response from SQL Server is empty
function checkValues(values){
    
    if (values === ''){
        // needs to be set to null if the SQL Server return nothing.
        // This is required to ensure JSON is correctly parsed. 
        values = null;

    }
    
    return values;
}



// execute request to pull the data
function executeRequest(request, connection){
    
    connection.on('connect', function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }

        connection.execSql(request);
    });
}

module.exports.createConnection = createConnection;
module.exports.createRequest = createRequest;
module.exports.executeRequest = executeRequest;
module.exports.configureRequest = configureRequest;
module.exports.runQuery = runQuery;
```

After this, everything else fell in to place. Then, I simply had to update the `router` so that it can return the data to the client.

```
 // POST add tags
 router.post('/tag', function(req, res){


    const data = req.body;

    let sql = `declare @result as table (id int, corporate_statement_link_id int, [name] nvarchar(50));
                with cte as
                (
                    select * from ( values (@corporate_statement_link_id, @name) ) as t(corporate_statement_link_id, [name])
                )
                insert into @result 
                select * from (
                    insert into dbo.tags (corporate_statement_link_id, [name])
                    output inserted.id, inserted.corporate_statement_link_id, inserted.name 
                    select * from cte 
                    where not exists ( 
                        select * from dbo.[tags] where corporate_statement_link_id = cte.corporate_statement_link_id and [name] = cte.[name]
                )) r
                select * from @result for json auto;`;

    
     try {
        
        var conn = sqldb.createConnection();

        //  var request = sqldb.createRequest(sql, conn);
        var parameters = [
            {
                'name': 'corporate_statement_link_id', 
                'type': TYPES.Int, 
                'data': data.corporate_statement_link_id
            },
            {
                'name': 'name', 
                'type': TYPES.NVarChar, 
                'data': data.name
            }
        ]

         var request = sqldb.configureRequest(sql, conn, parameters);

         // using the query above, check if the tag already exists or not, 
         // and if 
         sqldb.runQuery(request, conn, (result, err) => {

            if(err){
                res.send(500).send(err);
            }

            // The query above checks if the tag exists or not and inserts if it is not
            // If the data is already present in the database, then it'll return null. 
            // otherwise, it'll return the data that is inserted. 
            if(result === null){
                                    
                    res.status(409).send("The tag already exists");

            } else {

                res.send(JSON.parse(result));

            }
        
        });


     } catch(err){

        res.send(err);
     
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running two separate queries, one for the SELECT and one of the INSERT, which would actually require an explicit transaction to make sure that everything will always be consistent, you can execute everything with just one query, that will make also the code much simpler:

```
with cte as
(
    select * from ( values (4, 'tag6') ) as t(csid, [name])
)
insert into dbo.[tags_65648013] (corporate_statement_link_id, [name])
output inserted.*
select * from cte 
where not exists ( 
    select * from dbo.[tags_65648013] where corporate_statement_link_id = cte.csid  and [name] = cte.[name]
)
```

you can test the code using something like that:

```
drop table if exists dbo.tags_65648013;
create table dbo.tags_65648013
(
    corporate_statement_link_id int not null,
    [name] nvarchar(50) not null,
)
go

create clustered index ixc on dbo.tags_65648013(corporate_statement_link_id);
go

insert into dbo.[tags_65648013] values
(1, 'tag1'),
(1, 'tag2'),
(1, 'tag3'),
(2, 'tag1'),
(2, 'tag4'),
(3, 'tag2'),
(3, 'tag5')
go

select * from dbo.[tags_65648013]
go
```

Update: since OUTPUT do no support FOR JSON, you need to send the result into a @temp table and the query from there:

```
declare @result as table (id int, [name] nvarchar(50));
with cte as
(
    select * from ( values (4, 'tag66') ) as t(csid, [name])
)
insert into @result 
select * from (
    insert into dbo.[tags_65648013] (corporate_statement_link_id, [name])
    output inserted.* 
    select * from cte 
    where not exists ( 
        select * from dbo.[tags_65648013] where corporate_statement_link_id = cte.csid  and [name] = cte.[name]
)) r
select * from @result for json auto;
```

Comment: this is really interesting and helpful. This has been a really great learning experience for me. However, I couldn't figure out how to return the rows using FOR JSON PATH in the query. Any idea if I can do that using this query?

Comment: Uh right, I forgot about the JSON output :). OUTPUT do not support JSON. Edited the answer with a specific sample

Comment: That worked like a charm for returning json output without having multiple sql queries.