# How to insert data in multiple tables using single query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert data into multiple tables if it doesn't already exist. I can't seem to figure this out at all.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[search_results]
(
    [company_id] [int] NULL,
    [title] [text] NULL,
    [link] [text] NULL,
    [domain] [text] NULL,
    [index] [int] NULL,
    [id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)
```

Table 2:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[statements]
(
    [statement_link_id] [int] NULL,
    [statement_page] [text] NULL,
    [statement_text_location] [text] NULL,
    [statement_description] [text] NULL,
    [statement_description_html] [text] NULL,
    [statement] [int] NULL,
    [id] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
)
```

This is what I want to do:

check to see if the `company_id` and the link already exist in the table or not.

```
SELECT * 
FROM search_results 
WHERE company_id = 4 AND link = 'https://test.com';
```

If the data does not exist, insert it into two tables

```
INSERT INTO search_results (company_id, link, title, domain)   
VALUES (4, 'https://test.com', 'title', 'test.com');
```

and also insert the `search_result` last inserted id to the following table. `corporate_statement` value is always 1

```
INSERT INTO corporate_statements (statement_link_id, corporate_statement) 
VALUES (743, 1);
```

I'm trying this based on what I found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648013/how-to-insert-data-in-azure-sql-using-tedious-js-after-verifying-that-the-data-d/65660502?noredirect=1#comment116110784_65660502)

```
DECLARE @result AS TABLE (id int, company_id int, link text, title text, domain text);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (4, 'https://test.com', null, null)) AS t(company_id, link, title, domain)
)
INSERT INTO @result 
    SELECT * 
    FROM
        (INSERT INTO dbo.search_results (company_id, link, title, domain)
         OUTPUT inserted.*
             SELECT * FROM cte 
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.[search_results] 
                               WHERE company_id = cte.company_id 
                                 AND CAST(link AS varchar(250)) = CAST(cte.link AS varchar(50))
         )) r

SELECT * FROM @result;
```

Even trying with a single insert statement, I get the following error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

As you can see, I also tried to cast it to varchar since it was throwing error when I hadn't. How can update this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Why are you inserting into a table just to insert into another table? Finally, your @result table has 5 columns, you are selecting only 4 columns.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of that `INSERT` in a subquery syntax, to then do a further `INSERT`. Doing to other `INSERT` in the `OUTPUT` clause makes much more sense, in my opinion.

Comment: @Lamu, that's what I'm trying to figure out. What's the best way to do it then? I don't know much about it. I'm only trying to insert the data in one table which has relevant information installed, then use the inserted id to then insert into another table which has more information to be inserted. Table 1 and table 2 has one to many relation.

Comment: @marc_s, thank you for structuring it. I'm really struggling with this that I didn't pay attention to the proper structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me - this seems a lot cleaner, and it also will be a lot simpler to understand (and maintain!) in the future:

```
-- check to see if your data already exists
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM search_results 
               WHERE company_id = 4 AND link = 'https://test.com')
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- if not -> insert into the first table
    INSERT INTO search_results (company_id, link, title, domain)   
    VALUES (4, 'https://test.com', 'title', 'test.com');

    -- grab the last identity value from that previous INSERT       
    DECLARE @LastId INT;
    
    SELECT @LastId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    
    -- insert into the second table
    INSERT INTO corporate_statements (statement_link_id, corporate_statement) 
    VALUES (@LastId, 1);

    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- in case of an error rollback the full transaction
    ROLLBACK;
END CATCH;
```

and you're done. Or am I missing something? I *think* this would be doing what you're described in the intro of your post - not necessarily what you're showing in your code...

Comment: This is perfect. Not only you fixed the structure of my question, you also solved the problem. I didn't even know about BEGIN TRY, this statement you wrote is a treasure trove of information and learning material for me. Thank you for this!!

Comment: `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` probably a better idea than `CATCH ROLLBACK...`

Comment: @Kuni: it was user "divisionby0" who added the `BEGIN TRY..END TRY` stuff - thanks for that!!